# Cannot run simple compiled java program?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac

I am on Arch Linux, I just installed JRE and JDK and all the proper bin files (javac and java) are in /opt/java/bin/

I simply compiled a standard hello world, and compiled it with javac running `javac ./hello.java` and that made a class.

Now my problem is running it. I run java ./helloworld.class and it gives me an error, even if the file I point java to is non-existant:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: //helloworld/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ..helloworld.class
(..omitted for clarity..)
Could not find the main class: ./helloworld.class.  Program will exit.
```

You will notice the first line of the error, it munges the path `//helloworld/class`

When I feed java an absolute path, i.e `java /home/foo/helloworld.class` it gives the same error, but replaces the path's `/` with `.` in the first line, again munged.

What do you think is wrong? I really don't know why it is doing this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run java, you just pass it the fully qualified class name (including package), not the file name.

`java helloworld` will look for helloworld.class.

`java helloworld.class` will look for helloworld/class.class

Comment: Ah.. Perfect, that explains it all.

Answer (score 1):

You do not run a file as 
`# java file.class`
you run it as
`# javac PATH/file.java`
`# java PATH/file`

Do not add .class while using JAVA command.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should compile it like this

```
javac helloword.java
```

run the program

```
java helloword
```

Answer (score 0):

And yet another thing: add command line option "-classpath ." or it short version "-cp .", i.e. your command line should look like:
java -cp . helloworld

this is if your class is in your current directory. Otherwise "." should be replaced by path where the class(es) may be found.